# Earth Launch System with Water Propellant

Tags: rockets, launch, design-alternative, water, thrust

Water based thrusters have been proposed (and possibly tested by now) for use in satellites and other in-space vehicles - see [this NASA article](https://spinoff.nasa.gov/Spinoff2020/t_6.html). The idea is to perform electrolysis on the water to separate the oxygen and hydrogen into two bladders, then pumping them into a combustion chamber.

For some quick guesstimation math, the density of $H_2O=1 g/cm^3$; density of $H_2=0.07g/cm^3$; density of $O_2=1.14g/cm^3$. Volume needed for 1 g total of propellant is $29.45cm^3$ for $2H_2+O_2$ and $2cm^3$ for $2H_2O$ (take the inverse of each density to get volume per gram, multiply by 1 gram). So storing water as a propellant requires roughly 15 times less volume than an equivalent mass of separated hydrogen and oxygen (not including differences in equipment needed, just the propellants).

My question is this: could water be used as a propellant with an electrolysis engine in a 1st or 2nd stage rocket engine to launch from Earth?

Comment: The density of water is 1g/cm^3, not 2.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about that! I've shared your linked article with my social media. Thanks.

Comment: @RussellBorogove you're of course correct, and density does not change with increased portions... I should have been talking volume instead of density.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Just updated my calculations to match the correction, thank you. Let me know if this is wrong.

Comment: Where does the energy (or power) for the electrolysis come from?

Comment: @Jens it would have to come from stored power on the vehicle, or a very powerful (and probably large) power source. See the answers below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's run some numbers: A single Raptor engine consumes about $140 \frac{kg}{s}$ of methane, which is burnt in an oxidizer rich environment, i.e. the methane is burnt completely. Burning a kilogram of methane releases an energy of $55.5 MJ$. As such, a Raptor engine has a chemical power consumption of $7.77 GW$. **That's a couple power plants worth of power**.

Now, when you do electrolysis to create oxygen & hydrogen from water, you are expending the same amount of energy in the form of electrical power, as you regain as heat when you burn the two gases within a rocket engine. And, to avoid the necessity of large hydrogen/oxygen tanks on ascent, you need to produce your fuel as quickly as you burn it. That is, **you'd need an electrical power source as powerful as a dozen of power plants put together *right inside your rocket*.**

I guess, it should be obvious why this is totally infeasible.

Comment: Excellent break down. The speed at which electrolysis would need to occur is the part that I was missing. Thank you!

Comment: That's 6.4x more power than you need to run a time machine.

Answer (score 16):

Electrolysis-based propulsion becomes practical only once you've reached orbit, where you can power the electrolysis with solar panels and where you don't need enormous thrust.  Whatever you'd use to power electrolysis for a first stage would be much heavier than conventional chemical propulsion.

Comment: Not to mention the mass of the electrolysis cells themselves. And whatever you use to power the electrolysis would also have higher power output than the rocket engine you're fueling with the result. You'd be better off just boiling water directly.

Comment: Would remote power options not be viable, such as microwave or laser power transmission? That would eliminate the need to store most of the power onboard (maybe some small portion is still stored for emergencies and to supplement electrolysis in case of adverse weather conditions).

Comment: @Engineer_Chris A Merlin 1D rocket engine has an effective power output of about 3 GW, and the first stage has 9 of them, for a total exhaust power output beating the Three Gorges Dam. So, no, remote power supply is not viable.

Comment: We've built lasers powerful enough, but they can run only for a fraction of a second, https://lasers.llnl.gov/about/faqs#192_beams_produce.  And we sure don't have targets that can absorb that much radiation and convert it into useful power.

Comment: If you had such a laser you'd be better off just using it to boil hydrogen.

Comment: @ikrase provided you can solve the problem of boiling a launch vehicle booster's full flow of propellant using a laser beam from outside, without boiling the vehicle or its payload/passengers. In fact, even just melting them is generally considered bad.

Comment: In rocket engines, all the energy is released in a tiny combustion chamber surrounded by cooling channels that dump the absorbed heat right back into the combustion chamber, where it immediately gets exhausted out the nozzle. Only a tiny part of the system is exposed to the output power, and any cooling underperformance tends to result in engine-rich exhaust. In something that uses external power sources, you generally need to somehow carry equipment capable of manipulating that amount of power directly without evaporating. That's really, really hard to do in the typical mass budget available.

Comment: @ikrase it is difficult to heat neat hydrogen by shining light on it, as it is quite transparent. Water is much easier to heat and store. Getting the highest Isp isn't quite the be-all and end-all of rocketry ;-)

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I've seen one idea for a power supply for a high-energy laser launch system... it involves a MHD generator, driven by a Saturn rocket engine :-D http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/surfaceorbit.php#laserdetails

Comment: in addition to remote power being unfavorable to just using the remote power system to heat up the water directly, theres also the option of just keeping the electrolysis unit on the ground and using its outputs in a conventional rocket. You need an extremely mass efficient electrolysis unit for that not to be preferable when cryogenic storage is an option.

Comment: @StarfishPrime you might dope the hydrogen with sodium vapor or something, or burn it with just enough oxygen to vaporize it and run propellant pumps and provide some water content to absorb the power beam. Improving the performance of this particular system might make the difference between a system that's just ungodly expensive and one that can't even get off the ground...or you could just build a conventional bipropellant chemical rocket.

Comment: @user1937198 that also has the advantage that you can use a more-optimal O/F ratio...rockets rarely burn stoichiometric mixes, they usually use more fuel to reduce the average molecular weight in the exhaust and higher exhaust velocities, and to control corrosion of the engine.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff That and to reduce the risk of an engine rich mixture ratio.

Comment: @ikrase if you had such a laser, wouldn't just bouncing it back be a better source of fuel than hauling the extra propellant?

Comment: @John Dvorak for photon pressure? No, that requires a vastly more powerful laser.

Answer (score 7):

I'm pretty sure this wouldn't work as these types of thrusters don't have enough thrust to lift off against Earth's gravity. The HYDROS-C thruster (the focus of the article you linked) has a thrust of [>1.2 N](https://www.tethers.com/propulsion-system/), while (to use one example) the [Space Shuttle's solid rocket boosters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Solid_Rocket_Booster) each had 12-15 MN of thrust (depending on the stage of the launch). That's a difference of seven orders of magnitude.

Comment: The size of the HYDROS thrusters is also significantly smaller than those of the Space Shuttle. The same combustion process is used in both engines, so the thrust could be made comparable (if it were possible to overcome the power and weight issues).

Answer (score 6):

Water is the low entropy *product of combustion*.  (That's why it drip's out of you car's exhaust pipe, and is the reaction mass which spews out of the Space Shuttle's Main Engines.)  Thus, is order to use it as rocket fuel, you must first "uncombust" it, and that takes **a lot** of external energy.

This is in contrast to regular old chemical engines, which "just" directly combust their fuels.

Answer (score 1):

The point of electrolysis engines is to get the performance of hydrolox with a space-storable propellant.  You don't need space-storable propellants on the pad, even if you could somehow do it why would you?

Comment: One of the biggest reasons is safety. Water is non-combustible, making it far safer for astronauts.

Comment: @Engineer_Chris: Running a multi-GW nuclear reactor on the other hand will make it significantly less safe for the astronauts and everyone within a rather large radius. The fundamental problem is that the launch needs a huge amount of energy, and that amount of energy is going to be dangerous no matter what form it takes.